# Cached "Hot Meta Posts" are usually wrong, don't include their vote counts

Tags: discussion, feature-request

On the right hand side of the site we have the **Featured on meta** section that usually lists various community links such as hot meta posts.  This portion's voting score is almost never right due to I believe caching.

I believe the actual numbers are pretty pointless.  If I see a **hot meta post** and the title / subject line interests me I may click on it.  If not I won't even bother.

The numbers themselves are almost always out of sync and to avoid anyone asking why (since it's been asked numerous times) I'd say these numbers should simply be removed:

[image]

The one that says 23 currently has 28, the one with 8 currently has a score of 11, the one with 39 has a score of 41.  And this will probably change in the next minute...

Comment: Hmm, is the new UX mantra *all data should be correct*, given a somewhat similar discussion on [MSE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/273442/158100)?

Comment: @rene - The ambiguity with all these meaningless numbers is definitely an issue I'd say.  What problems does this cause you might ask?  Well simply confusion, people will not end the questions on meta only to find the question was asked a million times already and answered "Ohh it's due to caching".  People are people, not computers, when we see something say X is this..we believe than that X is really this and NOT that.  PS I agree with the post on MSE.

Comment: [Fixed for you](http://i.stack.imgur.com/3qaIg.png) ... I'm even willing to write a userscript until this gets implemented ;) ... joking aside: I get your point and maybe it is time to do some research on possible solutions.